# The aggregate function return wrong length of queries

Tags: mongodb

I have an issue with my aggregate function which returns wrong result length. I have 2 collections, the 'clients' and 'friends', the 'clients' collection have the geo coordinates and other important info like username and password etc... , in the 'friends' collection i store the client friends. I have this function that work well with one issue, it return wrong length results.

```
mongo.clients.aggregate([{
  $geoNear: {
    near: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: data.coordinates
    },
    maxDistance: 20000,
    distanceField: "location"
  }
}, {
  $project: options.options.projection
}, {
  $skip: 0
}, {
  $limit: 10
}, {
  $lookup: {
    from: "friends",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "friend_id",
    as: "friends"
  }
}, {
  $match: {
    $and: [{
      "friends.cust_id": {
        $nin: [ObjectID('5c86d093dea6161c0871ac34')],
      }
    }, {
      "friends.friend_id": {
        $nin: ["$_id"],
      },
    }]
  }
}])
```

So to understand what i am doing here, i will use "John" name as an example.
John has 4 friends and John want to find more friends near his location. When i am trying to get for John new friends from the "clients" collection, i want to exclude his current friends from the results and get him 10 new clients who are near him, but when i run my function, i get only 6 clients from the results but not 10. How can i keep the limit for 10 after i exclude his 4 current friends? 
Thank you

Comment: Because you have put `$match` condition after the `$limit`. So it filters from the 10 results which gives you even less documents

Comment: Wow, i didn't know that the position of the $limit condition should be after the $match to get the right length of results, thank you it worked :)

Comment: @VadimKorolov you can help the community by posting a solution to this answer and marking it as accepted.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean? I think Anthony Winzlet provided solution to this question.